# Save network images in Flutter to load them offline

Tags: firebase, flutter

How can I make a network image being available offline in my app? So, when I don't have network, it can be loaded from cache next time.

I'd tried `network_to_file_image` package and `cache network image` package as well, but it didn't work for me.

When I used cached network and I opened the app next time (without network) the images didn't load again from cache memory.

Here is the code where I use network image package in my Flutter app:

```
CarouselSlider(
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          autoPlay: true,
          height: 350,
          initialPage: 0,
          items: keyPlans.map((key) {
            File file;
            getData() {
              DirServices().file("loacliamge_${counter++}").then((File data) {
                file = data;
              });
              return file;
            }

            return new CarousalCard(
              image: NetworkToFileImage(file: getData(), url: key, debug: true),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ImageView(
                                image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(key),
                                text: appTitle,
                              )));
                });
              },
            );
          }).toList());
```

`network_to_file_image` package always fetch data from the network.

Comment: have you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Temp solution for `cache network image` package.

Add `IOFileSystem` class to your project, as described [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cache_manager/issues/238). (Hope this class will be available from package and we'll be able to remove this duplicated class in future)

```
import 'package:file/local.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/src/storage/file_system/file_system.dart' as c;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class IOFileSystem implements c.FileSystem {
  final Future<Directory> _fileDir;

  IOFileSystem(String key) : _fileDir = createDirectory(key);

  static Future<Directory> createDirectory(String key) async {
    // use documents directory instead of temp
    var baseDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); 
    var path = p.join(baseDir.path, key);

    var fs = const LocalFileSystem();
    var directory = fs.directory((path));
    await directory.create(recursive: true);
    return directory;
  }

  @override
  Future<File> createFile(String name) async {
    assert(name != null);
    return (await _fileDir).childFile(name);
  }
}
```

And then create CustomCacheManager

```
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';

class CustomCacheManager extends CacheManager with ImageCacheManager {
  static const String key = "customCache";

  static CustomCacheManager _instance;

  factory CustomCacheManager() {
    return _instance ??= CustomCacheManager._();
  }

  CustomCacheManager._()
      : super(Config(key, fileSystem: IOFileSystem(key)),);
}
```

Then finally provide this `CustomCacheManager` to the `CachedNetworkImage`

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  cacheManager: CustomCacheManager(),
  imageUrl: "your_image_url",
)
```

Then cached files won't be deleted by system between sessions